# How can I use nao_camera from nao_driver

Tags: ros, robot, nao-driver, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

When I run nao_driver, either in a simulator or on a nao robot (from my remote PC), I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jonfeme/nao_ws/src/nao_robot/nao_driver/nodes/nao_camera.py", line 156, in 
naocam = NaoCam()
File "/home/jonfeme/nao_ws/src/nao_robot/nao_driver/nodes/nao_camera.py", line 84, in **init**
if not self.cim.setURL( calibration_file ):
File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camera_info_manager/camera_info_manager.py", line 376, in setURL
if parseURL(resolveURL(url, self.cname)) >= URL_invalid:
File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camera_info_manager/camera_info_manager.py", line 514, in resolveURL
dollar = url.find('$', rest)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
[nao_camera-8] process has died [pid 4000, exit code 1, cmd /home/jonfeme/nao_ws/src/nao_robot/nao_driver/nodes/nao_camera.py --pip=127.0.0.1 --pport=9559 __name:=nao_camera __log:=/home/jonfeme/.ros/log/cf9cdbf2-e55e-11e3-a9ca-000c29578851/nao_camera-8.log].
log file: /home/jonfeme/.ros/log/cf9cdbf2-e55e-11e3-a9ca-000c29578851/nao_camera-8*.log

I cannot use nao_camera. I installed ros-hydro-info-manager-py, but I have still the same problem. The same happens with nao_speech.py.

I have Naoqi version 1.14.5, the other nodes work fine, but camera and speech not.

I will be grateful for any help.

Thank you very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/170061/how-can-i-use-nao_camera-from-nao_driver/) by [JonathanAI](https://answers.ros.org/users/18521/jonathanai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-05-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) on 2014-05-27**:
what do you launch from the command line ? Do you set NAO_IP and roslaunch the nao_camera.launch ?

**Comment by [JonathanAI](https://answers.ros.org/users/18521/jonathanai/) on 2014-05-27**:
Yes. I launch NAO_IP= roslaunch nao_driver nao_driver.launch force_python:=true

I also included the nao_camera node in the nao_driver.launch

All nodes are available, excepting nao_camera, nao_speech and nao_tactile.

Thank you

**Comment by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) on 2015-05-09**:
Please update to the latest code that should have handled those issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the same problem on Hydro and NaoQI 1.12.5 , nao_tactile is dying when launching nao_driver with this error

```
Exception TypeError: "in method 'module_getName', argument 1 of type 'AL::module *'" in <bound method NaoTactile.__del__ of <__main__.NaoTactile;  >> ignored
```

nao_speech is available though, and I can publish to /speech topic.
However, nao_camera is not working, I can't launch the process, because it's dying after throwing  exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/nao_driver/nao_camera.py", line 162, in <module>
    rospy.logerr('Something went wrong: %s' % (e.strerrror) )
```

I have managed to find the place, and it's throwing it on:

```
    self.nameId = self.camProxy.subscribe("rospy_gvm", self.resolution, self.colorSpace, self.fps)
```

Any ideas why that could happen, I am launching it with

```
PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/asiron/software/naoqi/lib:/home/asiron/software/naoqi/python
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ros/hydro/lib:/home/asiron/software/naoqi/lib
```

---

Originally posted by [asiron](https://answers.ros.org/users/18762/asiron/) with karma: 26 on 2014-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asiron](https://answers.ros.org/users/18762/asiron/) on 2014-06-04**:
Problem solved itself too, I don't know why but launch script was not reading properly ip address from NAO_IP env variable, and was crashing for this, now everything works